How to route messages from IoT Edge Module to Storage Account with IoT Edge hub routes?
I have an IoT Edge Module filtermodule which sends telemetry using send_message (docs) with IoTHubModuleClient every minute.
When I run this module, the IoT Hub message counter in the portal is incrementing. Also, I used this route in the IoT Edge Hub configuration for deployment:
"routes": {
  "filtermoduleToIoTHub": "FROM /messages/modules/filtermodule/outputs/* INTO $upstream"
}

Furthermore, I created a custom route and endpoint in IoT Hub which routes messages to a storage account (key based authentication). The route query is true and I tested the same telemetry data with the route and all tests pass in the sense that it matches the query.
Somehow the data is not ending up in the storage account and there is not really a straight forward way to debug why that is the case. Before I was using IoTHubDeviceClient with send_message (no IoT Edge) with the same route and storage account and data did actually show up in the storage account. What is missing here? I find the docs on IoT Edge and IoT Hub and how they work together quite confusing sometimes.
EDIT:
The telemetry data I send has the following format (the same format as when it worked previously):
{"Measurements": [{"Temperature": 20.5}, {"Temperature": 20.5}]}

I am using Terraform for deployment and this endpoint and route used to work:
# IoT Hub endpoint for bronze ingestion storage container
resource "azurerm_iothub_endpoint_storage_container" "bronze_ingestion_endpoint" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.this.name
  iothub_id           = azurerm_iothub.this.id
  name                = "bronze-ingestion"

  container_name = azurerm_storage_container.bronze_ingestion_avro.name
  connection_string = azurerm_storage_account.bronze.primary_connection_string

  file_name_format           = "{iothub}/{YYYY}/{MM}/{DD}/{HH}/{mm}_{partition}.avro"
  batch_frequency_in_seconds = 600
  max_chunk_size_in_bytes    = 10485760
  encoding                   = "Avro"
}

# IoT Hub route for bronze ingestion storage container
resource "azurerm_iothub_route" "bronze_ingestion_route" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.this.name
  iothub_name         = azurerm_iothub.this.name
  name                = "bronze-ingestion-route"

  source         = "DeviceMessages"
  condition      = "true"
  endpoint_names = [azurerm_iothub_endpoint_storage_container.bronze_ingestion_endpoint.name]
  enabled        = true
}

EDIT 2:
I can confirm that if I use IoTHubModuleClient.create_from_connection_string(conn_string) on my local machine, the route works and data shows up in the storage account. When I use IoTHubModuleClient.create_from_edge_environment() on the IoT device within the edge environment, the route does not work (but the message counter in the portal increments).
The same is true for Azure IoT Explorer. I can monitor incoming events from if I use IoTHubModuleClient.create_from_connection_string(conn_string) on my local machine, but nothing shows up If I use IoTHubModuleClient.create_from_edge_environment() on the IoT device.

@ poklaassen have you enabled  route ?

Yes the route is enabled

can you share the sample telemetry data which you are sending in above question

I included an edit, thanks

Use the az iot hub message-endpoint create command to create a custom endpoint that points to the storage container you made in the previous section. az iot hub message-endpoint create storage-container --connection-string $(az storage account show-connection-string --name $storageName --query connectionString -o tsv) --endpoint-name $endpointName --hub-name $hubName --container $containerName --resource-group $resourceGroup --encoding json

Use the az iot hub message-route create command to create a route that passes any message where level=storage to the storage container endpoint.az iot hub message-route create --route-name $routeName --hub-name $hubName --resource-group $resourceGroup --source-type devicemessages --endpoint-name $endpointName --enabled true --condition 'level="storage"'

and send the data to azure iot hub. It route the data to azure storage.

to run using  termform use null_resource. Refer to this link

I have just tried this, but that basically creates the same endpoint and route that was already created by Terraform. The result is the same, no data shows up in storage. When I look at the endpoints the status is unknown which according to the docs means that "IoT Hub has not attempted to deliver messages to this endpoint". So there must be something wrong with the IoT Edge Hub routing?

can you delete already existing routes and end point and use az command  by condition true like this using azure cli and run the send_message code again. --condition  true

use az iot hub message-endpoint create storage-container -n {iothub_name} --en {endpoint_name} -c {connection_string} --container {container_name}
Create a Storage Container endpoint for an IoT Hub using a connection string. The endpoint uri is omitted

Use iotedge logs <module_name> to inspect the logs for a specific module .(0r) Use sudo iotedge logs <ModuleName> -f to view the messages being sent from the module. Refer to this link to learn how to develop Azure IoT Edge modules using Visual Studio Code.

@Sampath I figured it out, but thanks for your help!

Apparently when you use /messages/modules/filtermodule/outputs/* you have to use send_message_to_output instead of send_message (documentation). I assumed that using send_message would send to any output, but that is not the case (documentation). send_message does work if you use /messages/modules/*, /messages/modules/<moduleId>/*, /messages/* or /*.

Below are the steps to send device data to Azure Storage using IoT Hub message routing:
From edge environment:

Use iotedge logs <module_name> to inspect the logs for a specific module .(0r)  Use sudo iotedge logs <ModuleName> -f to view the messages being sent from the module. Refer to this link to learn how to develop Azure IoT Edge modules using Visual Studio Code.

Create a azure Storage  and Container . Connect Endpoint for an IoT Hub Using a Connection String.
az iot hub message-endpoint create storage-container -n {iothub_name} --en {endpoint_name} -c {connection_string} --container {container_name}


Create a route using the following command:
az iot hub message-route create --route-name $routeName --hub-name $hubName --resource-group $resourceGroup --source-type devicemessages --endpoint-name $endpointName --enabled true --condition true



Run the send message code. Refer to this link for the send message code.

Refer to this link and this So tread for using Azure CLI commands in Terraform.


Now, you can send device data to Azure Storage using IoT Hub message routing.

